# AngularJs: '+' is displayed as %2b

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm using angular 1.2.28. When a user enters a name that contains a '+' it displays it as `%2b`, I tried using `decodeURIComponent` but it didn't help.

Any idea how to display the '+' sign?

```
 <li ng-repeat="bc in breadcrumbs" >
                        <a href="{{bc.link}}" ><span title="{{bc.name}}" ng-bind="bc.name"></span></a>
                    </li>
```

Comment: I can't replicate your problem using angular 1.2.28 in the following plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/H45sHvAGOBXlB1eSwhK7?p=preview. Can you create one and replicate your issue?

Comment: @Petrichor - tried it, didn't work :(

Comment: @fatman I think you should update your question to include more details and a Plunkr, too.